# Почему не удаляет обработчик

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```js
var func = {
    options: {
        'root': null
    },
    move: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('move');
    },
    down: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('down');
        this.options.root.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move.bind(this), false);
    },
    up: function() {
        console.log('up');
        this.options.root.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.move.bind(this), false);
    },
    init: function() {
        console.log('init');
        this.options.root = document.getElementById('button');
        this.options.root.addEventListener('mouseup', this.up.bind(this), false);
        this.options.root.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down.bind(this), false);
    }
}

func.init();
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Почему после отпускания мышки, не удаляется обработчик 'move'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Причина

Каждый вызов `Function.bind()` это отдельная копия той же функции и эти копии **РАЗНЫЕ**, то есть:

```js
function foo() {}
const a = foo.bind();
const b = foo.bind();
console.log(a == b); // false
```

Вот и метод `removeEventListener` не находит вашу первоначальную копию от `bind`, чтобы удалить.

#### Решение

Тогда что можно делать? Не надо `bind`-овать каждый раз, сохраните ссылку на копию и удалите:

```js
var func = {
  options: {
    'root': null
  },
  move: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('move');
  },
  moveCopy: undefined,
  down: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('down');
    this.moveCopy = this.move.bind(this);
    this.options.root.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveCopy, false);
  },
  up: function() {
    console.log('up');
    this.options.root.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveCopy, false);
  },
  init: function() {
    console.log('init');
    this.options.root = document.getElementById('button');
    this.options.root.addEventListener('mouseup', this.up.bind(this), false);
    this.options.root.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down.bind(this), false);
  }
}

func.init();
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Comment: Лучше создавать копию не в down, а в init

Comment: @PavelMayorov для таких ситуаций лучше создать класс и там нормально инициализировать, а не объект. Но тут я подгонял ответ в стиль автора, чтобы было понятнее и не мелочился настолько.